# possible to get mysql enum filed's index value in java?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('on','off') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'off',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)
```

I can use the enum index value to update or insert:

`update table set status=1 where id=12` (update id=2 `status` to `on`)

but in java,the Enum field type always return `String`   [(check here)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html)

`select status from table where id=2`

or use `resultSet.getObject("status")` (java)

always return the String `on`, but I want to get the Integer `1`

is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  CAST(`status` AS UNSIGNED) AS numerical_status
FROM `table`
```

Pitfall: This is 1-based, so you will get 1 for `on` and 2 for `off`

**Edit**

If you can't use calculated fields (for whatever reason), create a view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `table_numstatus` AS
  SELECT `id`,  CAST(`status` AS UNSIGNED) AS `status`
  FROM `table` ;
```

and direct your queries to this view, instead of the table.

Comment: +1 ,thanks ,this is vary helpful! if I can't change the SQL query,in JDBC,can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's not what you looking for but as solution you can create Java-enum on client side and convert according to its value